# “vendor" folder of Android file system

Tags: android, ios, shared-libraries, .so

I am developing an Android application which communicates with **iOS** device from an **Android** device using an **OTG** **cable**. I am using **Android** ported version of [libimobiledevice library](https://github.com/xxDroid/libimobiledevice-android). The library contains shared libraries (.so files) and binary executable files to establish communication between Android and iOS device using concept of **usbmuxd**.

This library requires to install certain .so files (shared libraries) to the location **“/vendor/lib”** and some binary executable files to the location **“/vendor/bin”**. After research I understood that these locations are accessible if the Android device is **rooted**.

I have following questions:

1. Why libimobildevice library will need such **root privileges**? In general, what types of advantages can be gained (in terms of permissions) by putting shared library files inside “**vendor**” folder?
2. Are there any the locations on Android device’s file system which are equivalent to the putting files inside “vendor” folder?

I have tested this library on my MOTO-X which is **not rooted** and I was not able to detect the attached iOS device from my Android application.

I’d appreciate any suggestions on this topic. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the github repo you links, the install position could be changed(in android/install.sh), have you try any other locations to install(like sdcard or data)?

For your questions:

1. **vendor folder** is seclabeled with **rootfs** and linked to **system/vendor** which is seclabeled with **system_file**, access permission of this location is controled by SEAndroid [sepolicy](http://www.androidcentral.com/tag/seandroid).

   ls -Z vendor
   lrwxrwxrwx root     root              u:object_r:rootfs:s0 vendor -> /system/vendor
   ls -Z system
   drwxr-xr-x root     shell             u:object_r:system_file:s0 vendor
2. I suggest you try other locations first. Or try to use it in a jni
       way?

wish this can help.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried to put all the binaries and libraries on SD card but as Android system don't allow SD card to give executable permissions to any files, I wasn't able to execute the binaries present on SD card. I had tried to use these .so files in jni way, but my application was not able to detect the attached iOS device.

Comment: I haven't used your tool. Suppose you should make sure if the tool works well. And use **adb shell dmesg | grep avc** or **adb logcat | grep avc** to find out if sepolicy permission was lacked